# Granted authority not working with hasRole()/hasAuthority() in SpringBoot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, jwt, authorization

I have a small applicaition that has a `CustomUserDetailService` Class. It essentially returns a user's role from the db, after they have been authenticated by using JWT.
This is the function that convert the roles from db to authority/role.

```
@Service
@Slf4j
public class CustomUserDetailService implements UserDetailsService {

    ................

    private Collection<GrantedAuthority> mapRolesToAuthorities(List<Role> roles){
        log.info("in mapRolesToAuthorities method");
        log.info("user's role - "+roles.get(0).getName());
        return roles.stream().map(role -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getName())).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I know this is working as I can get the user's role from the db with that `log.info()`.

Now i have a SecurityConfig class that I want to restrict the api's based on the roles.

```
@Slf4j
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception{

         httpSecurity
                .csrf().disable()
                ..........................

                .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers("/api/auth/**").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/h2-console/**")).permitAll()
                .requestMatchers("/question/**").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/quiz/**")).hasRole("USER")  //<< This is not working
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .httpBasic();   //  to make it into http than https
```

And I am getting **401 Unauthorized** error with the `/quiz` call. But i am able to access all the `permitAll()` ones.

This is the debug log with the `/quiz` call

```
2023-07-19T15:15:02.330+05:30  INFO 14024 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] c.l.q.security.CustomUserDetailService   : in mapRolesToAuthorities method
2023-07-19T15:15:02.331+05:30  INFO 14024 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] c.l.q.security.CustomUserDetailService   : user's role - USER
2023-07-19T15:15:02.331+05:30 DEBUG 14024 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to com.learn.quiz.controller.QuizController#getQuizQuestions(Integer)
2023-07-19T15:15:02.332+05:30 DEBUG 14024 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to com.learn.quiz.controller.QuizController#getQuizQuestions(Integer)
2023-07-19T15:15:02.333+05:30 DEBUG 14024 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#error(HttpServletRequest)
2023-07-19T15:15:02.333+05:30 DEBUG 14024 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#error(HttpServletRequest)
```

Things I have tried.

1. putting `.permitAll()` to the quiz endpoint -> it works as expected
2. Instead of `.hasRole()`, putting `.hasAuthority("USER")`, `hasAuthority("ROLE_USER")`, `hasAuthority("SCOPE_USER")` -> Fails everytime.

Answer (score 0):

You can add role based security at method level using the **PreAuthorize** annotation.

```
@GetMapping("/quiz/1")
@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('USER')") 
public String quiz() {
   ....
   return "someView";
}
```

If your method needs to support multiple roles, then use something like `@PreAuthorize("hasAnyAuthority('MOD', 'ADMIN')")` (this examples assumes that your role names are MOD and ADMIN respectively)

Comment: This is also not working for me. Tried with `@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('USER')")` , `@PreAuthorize("hasRole('USER')")`, and `@PreAuthorize("USER")`. No luck.